# Combining rows in a pandas dataframe

Tags: python, pandas

I have a dataframe as below

```
    text
0   hello
1   world
2   python
```

Is there any way where i can make it to

```
    text
0   hello world python
```

Comment: @reviewers I think this question should not be closed. The current close reason is obviously improper (this is not a debug question). Also, the question is clear and can be answered shortly, so it is neither "unclear what you are asking" nor "too broad". The only problem may be lack of efforts, but that [should not be a close reason](https://gaming.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5498/a-close-vote-is-not-a-super-downvote-please-dont-use-it-as-one).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use:

```
df = pd.DataFrame([' '.join(df['text'])], columns=['text'])
print (df)
                 text
0  hello world python
```

**Detail**:

```
print (' '.join(df['text']))
hello world python
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use [`pd.Series.str.cat`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/version/0.17.0/generated/pandas.Series.str.cat.html) to concatenate strings.

```
res = pd.DataFrame({'text': [df['text'].str.cat(sep=' ')]})

#                  text
# 0  hello world python
```

Answer (score 0):

In addition to the others:

python

```
def row_concat(x): 
     return x['1'] + x['2'] + x['3']

df.apply(row_concat, axis=1)
```